# How to capture compilation errors and warnings in SBT

Tags: sbt

My purpose is to write all compile warnings and errors to a file, that will be shown as a report file in Jenkins.

In this way, it is more clear to see the output of many tasks running in parallel.

How can I accomplish this with the compile task?

**UPDATE**:

I've researched a little and found:

- `compilerReporter`, but is is declared as private.  So it cannot be used.
- `bspReporter` task, that I don't know how to override

Answer (score 0):

The clue is to use the `compilerReporter` task.
As this task is defined as `private[sbt]`, the only choice is to create within the project an `AutoPlugin` in the `sbt` package.

This plugin will be responsible of overriding the default value of the task, and will have no problems as it is in the same package.

More info here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/5948